# Tkinter button disable not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Python and even newer to GUI programming.

I've got a button and two spinboxes that I want to disable after I click the start button.
I've Googled something 5 different ways to disable a Tkinter button and none seem to work.  Theoretically the spinboxes should be disabled the same way but I'm just not having any luck.
Getting really frustrated with the whole GUI thing.

`self.gps_com` and `self.arduino_com` are the two spinboxes

As you can see I tried to use the `update()` for the button but it doesn't work.  I've seen variations of the code that use disabled in all caps, first letter cap'd and different variations of quotes.  This current syntax gives no warnings/errors from Spyder.

I thought it was going to be easy to find the answer to this question but I've been at it now for a few hours.

```
def OnButtonClickStart(self):
    self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get())
    self.entry.focus_set()
    self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)
    self.button_start.config(state = 'DISABLED')
    self.button_start.update()
    self.gps_com.config(state = 'DISABLED')
    self.arduino_com.config(state = 'DISABLED')
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Spyder distribution supports the functions you're trying to use?

Comment: If you haven't tried, please try `Tkinter.DISABLED` or `"disabled"` (all lowercase with quotes[single or double won't matter] ).

Comment: Are you 100% sure that this callback is actually executed? Try putting some `print` statement in there. Also, is the button triggering any long-running operations that might be blocking the UI?

Comment: I commented out all additional code except for the GUI stuff.  I was making sure that as you suggested it wasn't getting blocked somewhere. Current iteration of code is just the GUI window with a couple of buttons and two spinboxes which I'm trying to disable from the click of the 'start' button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this piece of code and see if the text updates & the buttons disable/re-enable as expected:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window():

    def __init__(self, root):

        self.frame = tk.Frame(root)
        self.frame.grid()

        self.i = 0
        self.labelVar = tk.StringVar()
        self.labelVar.set("This is the first text: %d" %self.i) 

        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, text = self.labelVar.get(), textvariable = self.labelVar)
        self.label.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

        self.button = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Update", command = self.updateLabel)
        self.button.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

        self.enableButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "Enable Update Button", state = 'disabled', command = self.enable)
        self.enableButton.grid(column = 2, row = 0)

    def updateLabel(self):

        self.i += 1
        self.labelVar.set("This is the new text: %d" %self.i)
        self.button.config(state = 'disabled')
        self.enableButton.config(state = 'active')

    def enable(self):

        self.button.config(state = 'active')
        self.enableButton.config(state = 'disabled')

root = tk.Tk()
window = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

If this works than you are either a) using the wrong keywords (`'disabled'`, all lowercase, in Python 2.5/3.4 (I tested 3.4 last night)) or b) the function that you are trying to call is not being executed properly as tobias_k suggested.

Comment: Placing `print` statements in your function periodically is a helpful tip. I would suggest one before & after you try to change the state of the button perhaps.

Comment: Your code worked great.  Must be the callback not being executed.  Going to add some debugging prints to it and see what went wrong.

Comment: The import had the incorrect case for Python 3 at least. Set it back if you think that was in error. Your code helped me once I updated that line.